# Send Image using POST

Tags: c#, image, post

I have a WPF application and a ASP.NET MVC site. The WPF application uses the Kinect to capture images and these are saved as files. What I want to do is send the files from the WPF application to the ASP.NET MVC site.

I have tried the following which gets the bytes from the image file and converts it to a string using Base64 and then on the other side try to convert the string back to bytes and then back to a file. The whole process works except the files at the end are corrupt and won't load.

Also is the correct way of sending files or would I be better off trying to use Sockets?

**WPF Application**

```
var imageUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:18710/Home/Index";

//byte[] imageBytes = set.getImageBytes();
byte[] imb = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("imagename=" + ImageName + ".png&image=" + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(ImageName + ".png")));

var imageReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);

imageReq.Method = "POST";
imageReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
imageReq.ContentLength = imb.Length;


using (Stream os = imageReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(imb, 0, imb.Length);
}
```

**ASP.NET MVC Site**

```
if (image != null && imagename != null)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\" + imagename, Convert.FromBase64String(image));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing some weird stuff with encoding.  It's probably better if you pass the file name in as a header.. You can fetch the filename out on the MVC side.. by using HttpContext.Current.Request.  Then, just change your RequestStream you are writing in your wpf app, to this:

`byte[] imb = File.ReadAllBytes(ImageName + ".png")));`

Comment: How am I going to reassemble the file on the MVC side? When I look at Request.Form it has 1037 different keys.

Comment: Change your Content-Type to "image/png". Or application/octet-stream and make the parameter incoming to your index page.. "Stream myimagestream", from there you should be able to save the stream, wherever you want.

Comment: A stream.. is just a blob of "stuff".  You shouldn't be afraid of them.. -smiles- Once you realize that.. and that most file types can be uniquely recognized by the first 256 bytes of the stream.. you'll be a happier man. (Zip files are an exception to the 256 byte rule.. because a lot of files are really zip files.. modern powerpoint files.. jar files.. modern excel files.. )

Comment: That still returns the same thing in Request.Form.

Comment: You don't need Request.Form.  If you modified your "Index" Post method to take a parameter of a Stream myimagestream like this...
Index(Stream myimagestream)
You'll be able to just use the variable.

Comment: Or you can use this : 
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);

Comment: The 2nd one would be easier for you.. Man, you are making me work for this "Accepted" answer. : )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36497/discussion-between-slack-shot-and-priestvallon)